# Objective C Scripting Bridge with FileMaker Pro 11

Tags: applescript, filemaker, scripting-bridge

I'm trying to use scripting bridge to communicate with FileMaker pro 11, I can get it to launch the App, open the correct database file but can't get any further.

Has anyone got an example scripting bridge file for FileMaker Pro, once I can get my head around the communication between the 2 I should be OK.

I want to convert my app written in Applescript Studio to Objective C.
I know Objective C but can get my head around the communication between FMP.

Comment: are you trying to communicate with FileMaker over AppleScript/AppleEvents in an Objective-C program, or something else? Do you already have what you want up and running in Applescript Studio?

Comment: I have already completed the app in Applescript Studio with Applescript, but want to convert it to use the Scripting Bridge Framework. I don't want to use AppleScriptObjC though. Have a look here http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/UsingScriptingBridge/UsingScriptingBridge.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006104-CH4-DontLinkElementID_12

Comment: the header files should provide some insight, can you post them?

Comment: " can't get any further."  Like what?. Please post your code of where you are so far and explain what next you are trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

A while back I had to control iTunes from a Cocoa app using AppleScript and I used `NSAppleScript`. I wasn't aware of the Scripting Bridge, and I'll take a look at it, but it was pretty straightforward with `NSAppleScript`:

```
NSString *source = @"tell application \"iTunes\" to set sound volume to sound volume - 1";
NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:source];
[script executeAndReturnError:nil];
```

I never had any trouble controlling iTunes in this manner and I'm sure it would work with FileMaker as well.

One thing I'll mention that made writing the code a tiny bit easier was creating a category on NSAppleScript with the following method:

```
+ (NSAppleEventDescriptor *)executeWithSource:(NSString *)source {
  NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:source];
  return [script executeAndReturnError:nil];
}
```

That turned my scripting code into

```
[NSAppleScript executeWithSource:@"tell application \"iTunes\" ..."];
```